# Is there a way to inherit one trait in order to use all methods of this trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I've read [Extending Traits](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/extending-traits/1802/11), where the comment said:

> Rust has trait inheritance, it looks like this:
>
> ```
> pub trait A {}
> pub trait B: A {}
> ```

I tried to implement this Python code in Rust:

```py
class Animal(object):
    @classmethod
    def howl(cls):
        print("ao ao")

class Tiger(Animal):
    @classmethod
    def find_food(cls):
        print("find food")

a = Tiger()
a.howl()
a.find_food()
```

Rust way:

**lib.rs**

```
pub trait Animal {
    fn howl(&self) {
        println!("ao ao");
    }
}
pub trait Tiger: Animal {
    fn find_food(&self) {
        println!("find food");
    }
}
impl<'a> Animal for &'a str {}
impl<'a> Tiger for &'a str {}
```

**main.rs**

```
extern crate foo;
use foo::Tiger;

fn main() {
    "da".find_food();
    //    "da".howl();
}
```

If I want to use `howl`, I must import the `Animal` trait, and I don't think this is inheritance. Is there a way to inherit one trait in order to use all methods of this trait? How can I organize code to implement the above Python code?

Comment: so you just don't want to write `use colorful::{Tiger, Animal}` ?

Comment: @Stargateur Yeah, that's one way, but if this is called inheritance, why not just provide one trait for the user so that they can easily import this trait and use all methods, right?

Comment: this is not called inheritance but trait extending.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to import one trait in order to use all methods of this trait and its subtraits?

No.

Really, that amount of typing seems like a minuscule thing to worry about. If it bothers you that much, use a *glob import*:

```
use foo::*;
```

Some crates often have the concept of a *prelude*, a module with all of the commonly imported types and traits:

```
pub mod prelude {
    pub use super::{Animal, Tiger};
}
```

```
use foo::prelude::*;
```

> Rust has trait inheritance

This is a dubious statement. While we programmers are lazy and use the term "supertrait", it's not inheritance as programmers in classical object-oriented programming languages think of it. Really, it's just another type of trait bound:

```
trait Alpha {}

trait Beta: Alpha {}

// Basically the same as
trait Beta
where
    Self: Alpha,
{}
```

That is, any type that implements `Beta` must also implement `Alpha`.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I just didn't describe my question clearly, I know that I can import multiple trait with one line, I wonder is there a way to inherit methods of a trait like the above Python code?

Comment: @McGrady No. Rust does not have inheritance.